# JBoss para durante a inicialização do JSF 1.2 após conversão de projeto para o Maven

Tags: java, jsf, maven, jboss

Tenho um projeto rodando perfeitamente no **JBoss AS 5.1**, no entanto esse mesmo projeto **não foi concebido utilizando o Maven**. Isso quer dizer que o processo de gerenciamento de dependências ainda é manual e a *build* é feita pelo Ant.

O projeto não é muito grande e não possui muitas dependências. Sendo assim, resolvi "converte-lo" para o Maven. Então fiz os seguintes passos para converter ele todo:

1. Criei um projeto vazio com a estrutura do Maven;
2. Copiei os códigos fontes (sem fazer nenhuma alteração) para os respectivos diretórios (`src/java`, `src/resources` e `src/webapp`);
3. Logicamente, muita coisa não compilou, então fui adicionando no `pom.xml` dependência a dependência **nas mesmas versões** do projeto "original";
4. Após adicionar todas as dependências, o projeto compilou!

Então fui fazer o deploy no JBoss AS 5.1. Quando o JBoss vai inicializar o Java Server Faces para o contexto da minha aplicação, o JBoss simplesmente trava. Isso quer dizer que ele fica rodando, mas travado na seguinte linha:

```
...    
INFO  [config] Initializing Mojarra (1.2_16-20110421-1728-SNAPSHOT) for context '/minhaApp'
```

**Após ~8 minutos, explode um OutOfMemoryError!**

```
15:34:06,497 WARN  [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:javax.el.ELResolver
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:45)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(StringBuffer.java:91)
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.toExternalForm(URLStreamHandler.java:473)
    at java.net.URL.toExternalForm(URL.java:901)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.getRealURL(ZipEntryHandler.java:259)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.DelegatingHandler.getRealURL(DelegatingHandler.java:222)
    at org.jboss.virtual.VFSUtils.getRealURL(VFSUtils.java:1064)
    at org.jboss.classloading.spi.vfs.policy.VFSClassLoaderPolicy.getProtectionDomain(VFSClassLoaderPolicy.java:651)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:547)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:134)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:452)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:251)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:150)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:265)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:63)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:572)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
15:34:06,498 ERROR [[/minhaApp]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:200)
    at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener.contextInitialized(JBossJSFConfigureListener.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:45)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(StringBuffer.java:91)
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.toExternalForm(URLStreamHandler.java:473)
    at java.net.URL.toExternalForm(URL.java:901)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.getRealURL(ZipEntryHandler.java:259)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.DelegatingHandler.getRealURL(DelegatingHandler.java:222)
    at org.jboss.virtual.VFSUtils.getRealURL(VFSUtils.java:1064)
    at org.jboss.classloading.spi.vfs.policy.VFSClassLoaderPolicy.getProtectionDomain(VFSClassLoaderPolicy.java:651)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:547)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:134)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:452)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:251)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:150)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:265)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:63)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:572)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
```

Antes do erro reportado acima, **o Hibernate sobe perfeitamente**, valida todas as tabelas, o Hibernate Envers também sobe e checa as tabelas de auditoria. Tudo perfeito, só trava mesmo quando chega na hora da inicialização do JSF e **trava somente para o contexto da minha aplicação**. **Para o contexto *admin-console*, ele inicializa o JSF perfeitamente:**

Parece que tem haver com o **el-resolver**, mas procurei por problemas assim no Google e não encontrei nada.

```
...
INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/admin-console
INFO  [config] Initializing Mojarra (1.2_16-20110421-1728-SNAPSHOT) for context '/admin-console'
INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/
...
```

O que já tentei para resolver esse problema, **porém sem sucesso**:

- Retroceder versões do JSF e do Facelets;
- Alterar escopo no pom.xml do JSF para compile;
- Fazer deploy em máquinas Windows, Linux usando Java 32 ou 64 bits;
- Usando o JavaEE 7;

Tentei tantas outras coisas que não lembro. Meu **pom.xml** está assim:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.cpny</groupId>
    <artifactId>minhaApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Minha Aplicação</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.14</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-seam</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.ga</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.envers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-envers</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.GA-hibernate-3.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>minhaApp</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Repositório JBoss / Hibernate / JPA / EHCache -->
        <repository>
            <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
            <name>JBoss repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>

        <!-- Sourceforge -->
        <repository>
            <id>sourceforge</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/sourceforge/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <!-- EHCache -->
        <repository>
            <id>terracotta-releases</id>
            <url>http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Bom, após investigar mais um pouco vi que o Maven está empacotando a biblioteca `el-api.jar` dentro do pacote `war`. por ser **uma dependência do JBoss Seam**. Porém, no projeto "não maven" essa lib não vai empacotada. Então removi e fiz o _deploy_, e não ocorreu mais o erro. Mas ainda estou com o pé atrás vou continuar a investigar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problema resolvido!**

Minha aplicação utiliza alguns frameworks e bibliotecas. Um desses frameworks é o **JBoss Seam**, no qual a versão que estou usando é a **2.2.2.Final**. Nessa versão do JBoss Seam, a biblioteca `el-api.jar` é dependência e logo, ao fazer a build do meu projeto, essa biblioteca é empacotada junto com meu war na pasta `WEB-INF/lib`. No `pom.xml` a declaração do JBoss Seam é assim:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-seam</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

O problema ocorre porque também existe uma outra biblioteca (não sei se mesma versão) na pasta `<JBOSS_HOME>/common/lib`. Então, ao fazer deploy da minha aplicação, a minha biblioteca **provavelmente entra em conflito** com a biblioteca que vem com o JBoss, ocasionado o erro relatado na pergunta.

A solução é simples, basta adicionar a exclusão dessa biblioteca no pom.xml na declaração do JBoss Seam da seguinte maneira:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-seam</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Após fazer isso a biblioteca `el-api.jar` não será mais empacotada junto com o war e o **deploy é feito normalmente**. Mas assim que fiz o deploy e tentei acessar a primeira página, adivinha? **Outro erro**. Dessa vez o erro foi:

```
ERROR [facelets.compiler] (http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8180-1) Missing Built-in Tag Libraries! Make sure they are included within the META-INF directory of Facelets' Jar
ERROR [facelets.viewhandler] (http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8180-1) Error Rendering View[/login.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: Function 'rich:element' not found
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.visit(ExpressionBuilder.java:187)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:129)
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.prepare(ExpressionBuilder.java:138)
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:152)
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:206)
```

Esse erro aponta para alguma coisa relacionada ao facelets. Lendo ao pé da letra, aponta para alguma *tag library* faltante. Mas não é isso a causa do problema. Isso é algum **bug do facelets na versão 1.1.14** (que eu estava usando). Fiz o **upgrade para a versão 1.1.15** e o problema parou. Então basta atualizar a versão do facelets para sanar esse segundo problema.

A declaração do facelets no pom.xml ficaria:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.15</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Até agora a aplicação está funcionando perfeitamente!